# EdgeDriverManager MAC can not parse correct version by WebDriverManager

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java, selenium-edgedriver

I faced some issue downloading `msedgedriver` from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ by WebDriverManager.

For example my installed version - `Microsoft Edge is up to date.
Version 80.0.361.111 (Official build) (64-bit)` on MAC OS, but it did not display on the page that was parsed.

My solution was to add my CustomEdgeDriver and add new property to `wdm.edgeDriverUrl=https://msedgewebdriverstorage.blob.core.windows.net/edgewebdriver?comp=list` this link displays all available versions for EDGE.

I would like to ask guys from WebDriverManger, may you please fix this issue. Would be just great! Your service is cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with [WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) 5.0.1.